# @PostConstruct & Checked exceptions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, postconstruct

In the [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) doc it says about the annotated methods:

*"The method MUST NOT throw a checked exception."*

How would one deal with e.g. an IOException which can be thrown in such a method? Just wrap it in a RuntimeException and let the user worry about the faulty initial state of the object?
Or is @PostConstruct the wrong place to validate and initialize objects which got their dependencies injected?

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't noticed that. Seems like an odd restriction, given that the method is called reflectively.

Comment: `PostConstruct` method is for initializing objects. Why would you put something that throws `IOException` in an initialize method?

Comment: @Medopal: I'm checking for the existence of DB tables in the init method of a service, which throws IOException

Comment: @medopal redirecting or sending an HTTP error code also throw `IOException`

Comment: Is this constraint mostly from a philosophical viewpoint as in Exception must not be thrown while initializing objects or there is a bigger practical issue attached to it? I didn't fully understand this part why PostConstruct must not throw a checked exception

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, wrap it in a runtime exception. Preferebly something more concrete like `IllegalStateException`.

Note that if the init method fails, normally the application won't start.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, if you **want or expect** application start-up failure when one of your beans throws an exception you can use Lombok's `@SneakyThrows`.

It is incredibly useful and succinct when used correctly:

```
@SneakyThrows
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // I usually throw a checked exception
}
```

There's a recent write-up discussing its pros and cons here: [Prefer Lombok’s @SneakyThrows to rethrowing checked exceptions as RuntimeExceptions](https://www.databasesandlife.com/sneaky-throws/)

Enjoy!

Comment: You can have similar effect without using Lombok. Assuming you throw `SomeCheckedException` in your `init` method you could write `public void init() throws SomeCheckedException {` and result should be the same as with Lombok `@SneakyThrows`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a softened exception like so, in effect wrapping in RuntimeException:

```
private static RuntimeException softenException(Exception e) {
    return new RuntimeException("Softened exception.", e);
}
```

Then usage is like:

```
} catch (IOException e) {
        throw softenException(e);
}
```

Comment: How can this work? From what I see, you cannot just take an arbitrary exception and cast it to a `RuntimeException`. Sure the code will compile, but have you tried running this on the said `IOException`? I'm pretty sure you'll get a `ClassCastException` due to the fact that `IOException` does not inherit from `RuntimeException`. To truly get a `RuntimeException` you have to wrap the original exception in a new instance of `RuntimeException` or a subclass of choice.

Comment: Yeah, my code doesn't work right, but hopeully the basic idea, as you can see, is possible.